# Codeigniter devolver valor funcion controller

Tags: codeigniter

Tengo implementada una vista a la cual se accede desde una url llamando a una función,  ***Funcion 1***, dentro del controlador.

Esta vista tiene un formulario, el cual que se envía a otra ***Funcion 2*** (verificación) del controlador.

Y desde esta, dependiendo de los valores enviados, llama a otra función del controlador, ***Funcion 3*** (procesado), para que devuelva un fichero mediante *forze_download*.

Necesito recuperar en el formulario algo para que dependiendo de la respuesta, realice una u otra tarea.

***url -> Funcion 1 -> view -> submit -> Funcion 2 -> Funcion 3***

He probado a asignar una variable a la llamada de la Funcion 3 para que dependiendo de la respuesta, realice un redirect a la url del formulario añadiendo a esta una variable para tratarla en el formulario.

El fichero lo devuelve, pero no me devuelve la url con los datos

¿Por que no me asigna a la variable de la ***Funcion 2*** el *return* de ***Funcion 3***?

```
public function funcion1()
{
    $this->load->view('vista/mivista');
}

public function funcion2()
{
   ....
   $dat=$this->funcion3();

   if($dat==1)
      redirect("http://mipagina/funcion1?dat=1");
}


public function funcion3()
{
   ....
   forze_download('mytext.txt');
   return 1
}
```

Saludos

Comment: Es muy posible que tu llamada a `forze_download()` te esté provocando que no se llegue a ejecutar el `return` que hay debajo debido a que no esté encontrando la ruta del fichero. La función `forze_download()` puede recibir tres parámetros, dos de los cuales son opcionales. Al pasarle solamente uno lo que espera es la ruta donde se encuentra el fichero, por lo que me parece poco probable que `forze_download('mytext.txt');` te lo esté encontrando. Lo que haría sería eliminar esa linea para comprobar si te retorna bien la `funcion3`.

Comment: Hola,los ficheros me los devuelve correctamente, se abre el cuadro de dialogo para indicar donde guardarlo. Lo que no me devuelve es el valor del return. Saludos

Comment: ¿Te escupe la consola algún mensaje de error? ¿Estás cargando el *helper* apropiadamente con `$this->load->helper('download');` antes de usar la función `forze_download`?